# What is the purpose of a Label in an Amazon S3 Bucket Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In [AWS S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) there is a call out about labels:

> Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels
>   are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can contain
>   lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must start and end
>   with a lowercase letter or a number.

I have a use case where I have a bucket but now need to create another bucket that is region isolated.  For example, I have `my-bucket` in us-east-1 and now I want to create `my-bucket` in us-west-2.  Obviously I can't do that because bucket names are globally unique so I'm deciding between:

```
my-bucket-oregon
oregon.my-bucket
my-bucket.oregon
```

I can't find anywhere in AWS docs what the benefit of labels are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever name you want, as long as you stick to the character restrictions. The concept of a dot-separated label is to remain compatible with DNS naming standards, in case you ever wish to access the bucket via a URL that has the bucket name as part of the DNS Name.

Any of your above bucket names are fine. I would tend to recommend putting the 'common' part of the name at the front, with the region at the end, like this:

```
my-bucket-ap-southeast-2
my-bucket-us-east-1
my-bucket-us-west-2
```

(Or use use names like `oregon` instead of `us-west-2`.)

This way, the buckets with the same purpose will be grouped together when the buckets are listed alphabetically, which makes it easier to understand their purpose.

Comment: While fine and DNS compatible, potential issues with using dot-separated labels with the wildcard cert and Transfer Acceleration. From the AWS docs: 'We recommend that you do not use periods (".") in bucket names when using virtual hosted–style buckets.' ... 'The name of the bucket used for Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration must be DNS-compliant and must not contain periods (".").'